# Is it fine to create a base view model class with methods as events?

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, viewmodel

First of all, I'm a beginner in WPF and MVVM and my small app does necessarily not need all of the features to work, but I want to get the "imagination" of a big application and how it is really supposed to be done. So far, when opening new window, I have currently made a class called WindowHandler, that takes a viewmodel as a parameter and creates a view, like so:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
   new WindowHandler(new SettingsViewModel());
}
```

Creating the view:

```
public WindowHandler(ViewModelBase viewmodel)
{
    _viewModel = viewmodel;
    _view = new Window
    {
        Content = _viewModel
    };
}
```

Then I am able to add methods like Show() to my WindowHandler to open the window.

```
public void Show()
{
    _view.Show();
}
```

All my views, except for MainWindow, are usercontrols that are just content of windows. Now I bumped into a problem with window events. I could just add virtual methods for each window event into ViewModelBase and call them as usual view's events:

```
public WindowHandler(ViewModelBase viewmodel)
{
    _viewModel = viewmodel;
    _view = new Window
    {
        Content = _viewModel
    };
    _view.Closing += View_Closing;
    _view.Closed += View_Closed;
}
```

.. and then override them in viewmodel as wanted. But I'm starting to believe that I am going the wrong way. Can anyone say why this is wrong/bad and which way would I actually need to go?

Comment: Are all of your viewmodels actually going to listen to each of these events?  If not then forcing them to add a handler that does nothing is not adding much.  Inheritance can be a path to madness, and I'd suggest that you're going one step too far here.  Continue to write your code specific to the purpose of each viewmodel, and if you find that you're doing the same thing in every single viewmodel then pull it out in to a base class or composed-in handler.  Of course wrapping the window events up in a mockable interface is useful for your unit testing, so may be a good thing to do anyway